# What differences are between ObjectInput/OutputStream and DataInput/OutputStream when applying to instances of primitive types?

Tags: java, serialization, io

It seems to me that both `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream`, and `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` can apply to instances of primitive types.
What differences between `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream`, and `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` when they both apply to instances of primitive types?

Can they both (de)serialize instances of primitive types in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Don't use Java Serialization. Also `DataOutputStream` has some wacky formatting, so don't use that either.

`DataOutputStream` provides a layer over `OutputStream` that supports formatting data as required by Java class files. It doesn't add any tags/metadata, it just writes the data in a standard format. It's clearly part of an early compiler made public because it might be useful - typical of JDK1.00 classes.

`ObjectOutputStream` provides a layer over `DataOutputStream` (doesn't have to be implemented with that class, but the low-level data format is the same) that supports writing a specific file format containing arbitrary object data. As with most formats, this includes a bundle of headers.

When you write an object to an `ObjectOutputStream`, it'll also write the class description or a reference if it has been used since the last `reset`. The "data" methods are specified to format much the same as `DataOutputStream`, **but the file already has a header**. These methods are typically used in custom `writeObject` methods after `defaultWriteObject` or `writeFields`.

**tl;dr** There's a header with `ObjectOutputStream`; `ObjectOutputStream` is a (permeable) layer over `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Thanks. What are the recommended ways for Java serialization?

Comment: @Ben Everyone seems to be using JSON at the moment. Unfortunately that doesn't make a good job of specifying the format - it's not much higher-level that `DataOutputStream`. There's **loads** of Java libraries for JSON, I can't really help you select between them.

Answer (score 1):

That is something that you can easily find out yourself with a quick test:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1.out"));
            out1.writeByte(100);
            out1.close();

            DataOutputStream out2 = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("2.out"));
            out2.writeByte(100);
            out2.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this code, then you will directly see the difference:
The file of the ObjectOutputStream is bigger. ObjectOutputStream writes a total of 7 bytes instead of just one Byte which the DataOutputStream is writing.

The ObjectOutputStream is not just writing the core data. It is using the Java Object Serialization Stream Protocol which can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258